# Error: Text, Primitive, Image, CheckBox is not a valid value for StiStyleComponentType for stimulsoft

Tags: c#, wpf, stimulsoft

For reports I used stimulsoft in wpf .My Print Button code is :

```
try
        {
            DataTable dta = new DataTable();
            DataSet1.dtDataTable dt = new DataSet1.dtDataTable();
            List<KalaClass> list = MetroDataGrid.ItemsSource as List<KalaClass>;

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();

                row["id"] = item.KalaID;
                row["name"] = item.KalaName;
                row["tedad"] = item.KalaTedad;
                row["pice"] = item.KalaPrice;
                row["info"] = item.KalaTozihat;
                row["date"] = item.KalaDate;

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);


            StiReport report = new StiReport();
            report.Load("sReport.mrt");
            report.Dictionary.Clear();
            report.RegData(ds);
            report.Dictionary.Synchronize();
            DateTime today =Convert.ToDateTime( DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());

            (report.GetComponentByName("txtDate") as StiText).Text = convertDate.toShamsi(today);
            //(report.GetComponentByName("txtName") as StiText).Text = comboBox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
            //(report.GetComponentByName("Text1") as StiText).Text = txtid.Text;


            report.Show();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

I get "Text, Primitive, Image, CheckBox is not a valid value for StiStyleComponentType." Error in

```
  report.Load("sReport.mrt");
```

I tried but I cant find why i get this error. How can I fixed it ?

Comment: It's something wrong with your report template. Where did you get it? Try to open it in the Designer and save it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my Stimulreport's dll have problem. I deleted it and add new version . so I fixed it .